# How to declare multiple font-face and assign each of them to a variable and access them in styled-components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I am using font-face in `index.css` and accessing these font-family in other places of my application.

My requirement is to assign each of these font-face to different variables. And use these variables in my applications. I want to name these variables generically as 'regular', 'medium' because if I change it from `OpenSans` to other font-family I need not change font-family as `OpenSans` to other in other parts of my application.

I am using `styled-components` for stylings .

```
@font-face{
  font-family: 'OpenSans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(./assets/Fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf)
}

@font-face{
  font-family:'OpenSans-SemiBold';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src:url(./assets/Fonts/OpenSans-SemiBold.ttf)
}

@font-face{
  font-family:'OpenSans-SemiBoldItalic';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src:url(./assets/Fonts/OpenSans-SemiBoldItalic.ttf)
}

@font-face{
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(./assets/Fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.ttf);
}

@font-face{
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova Medium';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(./assets/Fonts/proxima-nova-medium.ttf);
}
```

Also, once these font-faces are assigned to different variables how can I access in styled-components of other components
eg:

```
const p = styled.p`
font-family: ??? --> is it using ${variable_name} ?
`
```

my requirement in index.css :

```
var Medium-font = {
    @font-face{
      font-family: 'Proxima Nova Medium';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      src: url(./assets/Fonts/proxima-nova-medium.ttf);
    }    
  };

var Regulat-font = {
    @font-face{
      font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      src: url(./assets/Fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.ttf);
    }
  };

and so on..
```

Comment: I would do it in SASS. Where do you want to put your code?

Comment: @VictoriaRuiz want to place it in index.css of my app

Comment: If SASS is not an option, use this: https://codeburst.io/css-variables-explained-with-5-examples-84adaffaa5bd

Comment: People, you have SASS built-in in styled component, try not to misslead.

Comment: @VictoriaRuiz, how to assign each font-face to different variables and wrap inside a :root selector

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to assign the whole `font-face` to a variable. Fonts are NOT something that you change often. But even if you do for some reason... the `font-face` will still need to be changed like url and the name of the font itself in the index.css but the only change in actual css will be the `font-family` property.

You can just assign the `font-family` to a variable in styled-components and then use it everywhere. This way you'll only need to change it in one place in your theme.

You can use `ThemeProvider` to achieve this.

```
// Some component
const Para = styled.p`
  font-family: ${props => props.theme.fontFamily1};
`;

const Para2 = styled.p`
  font-family: ${props => props.theme.fontFamily2};
`;


// Define what props.theme will look like
const theme = {
  fontFamily1: "OpenSans",
  fontFamily2: " Proxima Nova"
};

//render method of App.jsx or root app file
render(
  <div>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Para>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</Para>
      <Para2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</Para2>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </div>
);
```

`<Para>` compoent will now have the font ***OpenSans*** and `<Para2>` ***Proxima Nova***.

If you decide to change the font, just change the fontFamily1/fontFamily2 prop in theme accordingly and it'll reflect in all the components using the theme.

Refer this for more info: https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#theming

Hope this helps !

Comment: I am using the same code base for other client which uses other font-family. That is the reason I have this requirement.

Comment: I'm not sure how that is relevant to the question.

Comment: Declare multiple fonts in `index.css` , assign them to a variable in theme and then use it in your styled components.